# Physics Stack Exchange "Ask me anything" (AMA)

Tags: discussion, chat-events, ask-me-anything

## Purpose

The user base of Physics Stack Exchange is rather diverse in terms of cultural background, career progress, field of expertise, and personality.
While the discussion in hbar is lively, it is mostly focused on physics, with some side conversations on a variety of topics from cooking to favorite software bugs.
However, it could be interesting to set aside dedicated time in which to learn more about each other as individuals.
This could be of interest to most users due to normal human curiosity, and especially useful for students who would benefit by exposure to those whose hindsight can help avoid common pitfalls in physics and in life.

These kind of sessions, called "ask me anything" or "AMA" have a solid history in other online communities, particularly on reddit.

## Schedule

#### Upcoming

- [C. Jess Riedel](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/7911/jess-riedel): [website](http://jessriedel.com/), [CV](http://jessriedel.com/index_files/CJR-CV.pdf), [Blog](http://blog.jessriedel.com/). Date to be determined.

#### Previous

- [Mithrandir24601](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/114272/mithrandir24601), August 22nd 2017

  - [Question pool and details](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10085/84967)
  - [chat session](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/conversation/ama-mithrandir24601-2017-08-22)
- [Jim](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/23473/jim), July 24th 2017

  - [Question pool and details](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10000/50583)
  - [chat session](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/conversation/ama-jim-long-may-he-reign-2017-07-25)
- [Bernardo Meurer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/50764/bernardo-meurer), June 13th 2017,

  - [Question pool and details](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9898/50583)
  - [chat session](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/conversation/ama-bernardo-meurer-2017-06-13)
- [heather](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/121464/heather), Monday, February 20th 2017, 10pm UTC

  - [Question pool and details](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9613)
  - [Chat session](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/conversation/ama-heather-2017-02-20)
- [Secret](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/64669/secret?tab=profile), 6 September 2016

  - [Question pool and details](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9056/september-6-physics-ama-secret-question-pool)
  - [Chat session](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/71?m=32143865#32143865)
- [DanielSank](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/31790/danielsank?tab=profile), 12 August 2016

  - [Question pool and details](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8981/august-23-physics-ama-with-daniel-sank-question-pool)
  - [Chat session](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31650865#31650865)
- [yuggib](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/50546/yuggib), 12 July 2016

  - [Question pool and details](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8814/ask-me-anything-12th-july-guests-introduction-and-questions)
  - [Chat session](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/71?m=30980294#30980294)
- [slereah](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/36941/slereah), 14 June 2016

  - [Question pool and details](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7782/questions-for-the-june-14th-ama)
  - [Chat session](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/71?m=30352471#30352471)

## Contributing

If you'd like to be a guest speaker, or moderate an AMA session, please ping @DanielSank or @vzn in the [hbar](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar).
If you'd like to improve our [community ad art](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7768/31790), please just submit an edit.

## Resources

- [Discussion of AMA format (meta)](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7778/what-format-should-we-use-for-physics-stack-exchange-amas)
- [Discussion of the first AMA session (meta)](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8815/what-was-your-impression-of-the-the-first-ask-me-anything-ama-event)

Comment: Nice presentation of the data at the first sight; kudos @Daniel for the contribution.

Comment: msg to all: venue is the [H Bar chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar), one of the busier/ more active on SE, plz feel free to drop by any time, propose questions/ guests, chat about physics or other stuff; so far the invited guest speakers have come from the pool of "regular chat users" and may be available to chat at other times. SE chat is full featured & theres also a complete searchable transcript by words & users, starring system for notable chat lines, inline images, mathjax, etc