# Ask Me Anything 12th July: guest's introduction and questions

Tags: discussion, chat-events, ask-me-anything

I will be the next [AMA](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7783/physics-stack-exchange-ask-me-anything-ama) guest. So here it is a brief introduction of myself, and you can suggest some topic/questions that can be discussed during the session.

**Academic Background.** I obtained a master degree in theoretical physics almost ten years ago, working on the regularization of path integrals for supersymmetric QM models of particles in curved (Euclidean) background space. In particular, I focused on the mode regularization, both for the phase space and usual path integral, in N=1,2 SUSY sigma models. It has been a while, however, since I abandoned those topics.

Then, following the same *cursus honorum* as many others in [my community](http://www.iamp.org/page.php?page=page_start), I shifted towards mathematics. My motivation was - and still is - that I don't like the sloppiness with which many subtle and interesting mathematical problems are dealt with in theoretical physics. I therefore did a Ph.D. in mathematics, with analysis and mathematical physics as main topics. During my Ph.D. I started working on the so-called mean field and classical limits of quantum (field) theories; i.e. on rigorously proving the emergence of classical/mean-field effective dynamics starting from the full quantum description of a given system. This is still my main area of research, but I also work in scattering theory (e.g. for Lindblad superoperators) and nonlinear partial differential equations of physical relevance.

**Suggested topics.** Below you can find a list of the topics on which it is more probable that I would have something meaningful to say, but feel free to ask anything else.

- Classical and mean field approximation of quantum systems (e.g. Bohr's correspondence principle; the emergence of Hartree, Gross-Pitaevskii, Vlasov, Hartree-Fock dynamics from many-body quantum systems; ...);
- The interplay between rigorous mathematical results and physics (e.g. Haag's theorem, the von Neumann measurement scheme, representation theory for the algebra of canonical commutation relations, ...);
- Partial Differential Equations "of evolution" (e.g. Schrödinger, Wave, Klein-Gordon, Dirac, ...);
- Mathematical foundations of quantum mechanics and quantum field theory;
- Quantization (from a mathematician's point of view).

In general, I think I could at least point to some references if you ask me questions about mathematical physics, apart from some topics on which I am quite ignorant (like e.g. all things related to homology/cohomology applied to physics, string theory, general relativity).

Also, even if I am not at all an expert, I like to read about logic, set theory, and in general the problems that arise in foundational mathematics. So this could also be a topic for a (very informal but interesting) discussion.

**When and where.** The AMA session will take place in the hbar chat room, the 12th of July at 16:00 UTC.

Comment: thx very much for agreeing! you are the 1st PhD guest in the series :) ... re you say you "graduated in theoretical physics" but that sounds like a very advanced topic for an undergraduate degree, do you mean a masters or Phd degree in physics? which country/ school, if possible? also plz point/link to any publication(s) esp online.

Comment: @vzn: '_which country/ school'_ - I think we should provide a scope to our guests for maintaining anonymity if they want.

Comment: @vzn It's a pleasure ;-)

Comment: Do you know and is it possible to explain in this format how renormalisation can be done and interpreted in a mathematically rigorous fashion?

Comment: @Martin well yes, that is a good question ;-) If you want to elaborate it a bit more, you can put it as a question below (e.g. if you are more interested in the perturbative/non-perturbative renormalization, which models, ...)

Comment: Hi. May I ask if you have any interests and knowledge on many-particle relativistic quantum mechanics as a different approach rather than QFT? (Possible subjects would even be the equivalence efforts between the two disciplines). Thank you.

Comment: @ConstantineBlack What do you mean exactly by "many-particle" relativistic quantum mechanics"? Do you mean systems of many particles obeying e.g. Dirac or Klein-Gordon equations instead of Schrödinger ones (possibly with nonlinear couplings)? As I suggested to Martin as well, you could maybe expand the question a little bit as an answer below ;-)

Comment: Thanks for replying. I do not mean something like Dirac or KG equations but something like that: http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~neum/physfaq/topics/multi.html . The reason I didn't post this as a question is because I am not sure if this is inside your field interests. If it is on any level, please clarify and I will be happy to post a complete proposal of some personal interest that could be addressed from you during the interview. Just note that what I mean is not similar to taking the above equations you mentioned and go quantize them via canonical or geometrical field quantization. Thanks.

Comment: @ConstantineBlack I don't know much about that, no. Anyways, you can still provide some details if you want ,or ask about it anyways during the chat session ;-)