# Privacy (https) error for AMA link in the Upcoming Events list

Tags: bug, status-planned

When trying to go to the highlighted discussion
[Ask Me Anything 12th July: guest's introduction and questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8814/ask-me-anything-12th-july-guests-introduction-and-questions?cb=1)
my chromium browser gives an error message,

> Your connection is not private
>   Attackers might be trying to steal your information from meta.physics.stackexchange.com (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID''
>
> This server could not prove that it is meta.physics.stackexchange.com; its security certificate is from *.stackexchange.com. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.''

Something similar on firefox.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to access the meta site over HTTPS. This is not supported yet, because it's impossible to configure a certificate for all (150+ of them) meta.*.stackexchange.com sites.

So, to make things work, SE developers will switch the meta URLs to *.meta.stackexchange.com, for example this site will be http://physics.meta.stackexchange.com. This is [being worked on](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327639/use-https-for-snippets-because-some-features-are-https-only#comment365342_327639). Until then, either use HTTP for accessing the meta, or ignore the warning about invalid certificate.

Comment: But the link (on the right, ''UPCOMING EVENTS'') contains https:// hence pretends to be secure. So that link should be changed!

Comment: @ArnoldNeumaier OK done, although it would be irrelevant after another hour anyway.

Comment: @DavidZ Sure - but it's good to keep in mind for future go-rounds.